# Find everything except the search match

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to write a notepad ++ regex to match everything besides my search criteria.

Fore example, if I have

```
James Bond (E1R1)
```

I have a regex to match E1R1. But I need to reverse it so I can get rid of everything besides E1R1.

So far I have `^(?!(?<=\().+?(?=\))$).*$`. But it seems to match everything.

Comment: Capture groups my friend, capture groups. Find `^.*(E1R1).*$`. Replace `$1`

Comment: Can you please explain what you think the regex `^(?!(?<=().+?(?=))$).*$` does. I do not see `E1R1` anywhere within it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^.*\(([^()\n\r]*)\)$|^(?!.*\(([^()\n\r]*)\)$).*\R?
```

Replace with `$1`.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/JCIzLR/1).

The expression finds lines ending with round brackets at the end, and removes all text outside those brackets. It will remove the entire line that contains no brackets at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could match from an opening till closing parenthesis and skip that match. Then match any single character which should be replaced by an empty string.

```
\([^()\r\n]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|.
```

**Explanation**

- `\([^()\r\n]*\)` Match from an opening till closing parenthesis `(....)`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip the match
- `|` Or
- `.` Match any character except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s9UuFv/1)